# how can i make this divider just below

Tags: flutter

I want to add a divider just below the container, what should I do as seen in the picture?

[image: di]

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far ?

Comment: You could take a look at this Flutter tutorial / codelab I created where I made a custom tab bar like that and did that same effect https://romanejaquez.github.io/flutter-codelab-cr2-2/#11. See if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the widget `Divider(height: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow the given layout please refer and change your Layout then you will get the Divider under the Tabs

```
Column(
  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
        child: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: tabChildList,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab),
      ),
    ),
    const Divider(
      height: 1,
      thickness: 1,
      color: ThemeColor.disabledColor,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: tabBarViewChildList,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```